# transaction pendin for 7 hours now

Tags: pending-transactions

my transaction from ledger wallet to my binance wallet has been pending for 7hours now. 
I guess I haven't set up enough fees for the transaction.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x05bf67b361708b43f90e3ebb1154b96923a2614998e8bf2eddbe2a1b511cf18d

Should I wait again ? Or do I have the option to speed up this ? 
If some has a way forward to propose I take it

Comment: Send it using the same account and the same nonce, but with a higher gas price.

Comment: thanks mate but how should I do? I mean I already sent it... How can I resend it with an higher price ? the from address is my ledger wallet and I don't have any ETH to resend a transaction... I'm novice

Comment: Ah, you'll need some Ether for sure, but don't worry, the previous transaction will not be added to the blockchain, meaning you'll get the Ether from that transaction back into your account.

Comment: ok do you how long it could take ? just to know if it worth the fact of adding few ETH on my wallet to make the transaction you are talking about

Comment: I made another transaction from the same account (ledger). But I couldn't set up the nonce... any idea ? now I have 2 transactions pending https://etherscan.io/address/0xa75ec1bd696e7d1fd0a09671cb723ee964e4bfe8

Comment: any idea how to set the nonce ?

Comment: From a node.js script, you just pass it as part of the transaction. Are you using a node.js script for sending your transaction?